# Open activity automatically without clicking the notification in a tray

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make an application which will trigger the phone from the Firebase by sending a push notification. When the notification arrives, I want to open Emergency Class, but it only call the Emergency class when application is in foreground. When application is on background, notification arrives on notification tray and Emergency class will not be executed.

Also, I am trying to toast the message from the database, but for some reason, the String is Empty. Can someone help me to find a solution or post a simple example of it?

Thank you.

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private Handler HandleIt = new Handler();
String messageContent = "";

public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    messageContent = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    postToastMessage(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

public void postToastMessage(final String message) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message +" received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, Emergency.class);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(newIntent);

        }
    });
}

private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(" Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.info)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: are you sending a notification from the firebase console?

Comment: yes, I am sending from the console

Comment: I think this might help: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-android-background

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I already knew that. My question is how can I  call onMessageReceived even when it is on the background. Or what to do to call Emergency Function when app is on background ?

Comment: You need to send a Data payload with your server, see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: I think, I know what you are talking about. Thank you.

Comment: got answer for this @ilia sidamonidze ??

Comment: @SachinVarma Please tell me what is the answer. I know it's too late but I'm actively looking for it's answer